# GitLab 100% CPU usage by unicorn when accessing specific commit

Tags: git, gitlab, cpu, unicorn

this is my first question here,
so I have GitLab working on one of my server, but recently I cannot access my gitlab because of 502 error that says "Taking too much time to respond".

I have about 50 users on my gitlab.
When one of my users access his last two commits, unicorn starts using 100% of CPU and not allows anyone else to work, so gitlab stop working. 
Everything else is working. Everyone can see their commits, but when accesing this one, I need to restart gitlab to make it working again.

Gitlab is installed on partition which have 10GB of space, and **only 500MB left**,
2GB of RAM, and 1 gb swap. 1vCPU(AWS instance)

My configuration is:

```
  System information 
    System:         CentOS 6.7 
    Current User:   git 
    Using RVM:      no 
    Ruby Version:   2.1.8p440 
    Gem Version:    2.5.1 
    Bundler Version:1.11.2 
    Rake Version:   10.5.0 
    Sidekiq Version:4.0.1

    GitLab information 
    Version:        8.4.3 
    Revision:       eb6f691 
    Directory:      /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails 
    DB Adapter:  postgresql 
    URL:            http://git.mydomain.lol 
    HTTP Clone URL: http://git.mydomain.lol/some-group/some-project.git 
    SSH Clone URL:  git@git.mydomain.lol:some-group/some-project.git 
    Using LDAP:     no 
    Using Omniauth: no

    GitLab Shell Version:        2.6.10 
Repositories:   /projects/git-data/repositories 
Hooks:          /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/hooks/ 
Git:            /opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/git
```

There is nothing in logs, except in unicorn where says Unicorn killer exceeds memory limit.

So if you need more details, please feel free to ask I will provide you anything,

thanks for help !

Comment: 1vCPU and 2GB of RAM is not much for a gitlab instance especially with 50 users (see https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/install/requirements.html#memory). Also the version you are using is a bit old, I would recommend moving to a more recent version as performance improvements have been added since.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that upgrading to the latest stable version is a good place to start. I had the same problem - 100% CPU consumption caused by persistent sidekiq jobs. I had GitLab running with 8GB RAM and 4 CPUs. For my 16 users, that should've been more than enough. After upgrading from 9.1 to 9.2  (source install), the sidekiq processes stopped eating up all my RAM and CPU and everything was fine again.I think this is because you clean up old gems and clear the Ruby cache as part of the update process.

For deeper troubleshooting, check out [GitLab's recommended tools](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/troubleshooting/sidekiq.html).